# Vim YouCompleteMe overzealous autocompletion

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I'm (trying) switching to vim but YouCompleteMe is giving me a hard time. It is just autocompleting the wrong thing way too fast when there are many options. Generally the second item. My other settings are good and I'm happy with them. I've heard this issue is from conflicts in the .vimrc. Anyone know what the conflicts could be. I feel like I need all these settings to get everything else to work properly...

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
let g:tsuquyomi_disable_quickfix = 1
let g:syntastic_typescript_checkers = ['tsuquyomi']
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
set ballooneval
autocmd FileType typescript setlocal balloonexpr=tsuquyomi#balloonexpr()
autocmd FileType typescript nmap <buffer> <Leader>t : <C-u>echo tsuquyomi#hint()<CR>
set nocompatible
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
setlocal indentkeys+=0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eh, silly mistake I use NVM and hadn't set `nvm use` to the version so that was causing the issue.

Comment: I'm having that same issue and it isn't (I think) related to nvm. ps shows it using the correct version of node and typescript.

Comment: I’ve since moved in to neovim which seems to work much better for me. Deoplete is a great autocomplete engine there.